# Have I found both biological parents, one biological parent or should I keep looking?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, 23andme

My husband's mother was adopted without any records (1910 NYC).  I located her biological paternal family along with several possible brothers through DNA. I cannot locate her biological maternal family (all matches circle back to the paternal side).

Just tested on 23andme and my husband has a first cousin match.  They are of similar age so same generation. They share 805cM DNA, they 1/2 share the entire chromosome #13 and they 1/2 share 126cM of X-DNA (30cM and 96cM segments).

My husband's father is of a different ethnicity and his first cousin's father is not a consideration either. The cousin's maternal grandfather is from the family I identified as my husband's mother's paternal family.

Have I located both biological parents, one biological parent or none for sure?